# custom role and front end with distributed cache

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, minrole

i am using custom role with performance point service and the farm working but when i checked 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910(v=office.16).aspx and custom role not refer to performance point service!!!

which role to use custom role or front end with distributed cache role?!!

I am confused , please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With every role their is dedicated set of services auto provisioned with configuring that role as per the technet. But if you try to provision any other service which is not listed for that role then you will see a health rule error and also that service will be stopped to make that server complinced with minrole.

With custom role you can start any services on the server. All services are supported and server will be stay in the compliance.

Comment: thanks sir, today  you help me alot :) , will i  see a health rule error and also that service will be stopped to make that server complinced with minrole. with custom role ?

Comment: With custom role their will be no compliance related error in health rule...but u will see error if service is not working properly